# Error : Could not determine access type for property "articlesCategories" in class "Articles"

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I am using Symfony 3.4.7 . I work with 3 linked entites, Article, Categorie and ArticlesCategories. ArticlesCategories is the relation table.

I would like to add and edit articles. I wish I could Add / Edit articles, given that an article may have several Categories and vice versa. I have attributes specific to the relationship in the relation table , that's why I created the relation entity.

This is the code of an Articles :

```
/**
 * Articles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticlesRepository")
 */
class Articles
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code_article", type="string", length=10)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $codeArticle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var ArticlesCategories
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ArticlesCategories", mappedBy="codeArticle")
     */
    private $articlesCategories;
    // getters et setters normaux
...
    /**
     * Add articlesCategorie
     *
     * @param ArticlesCategories $articleCategorie
     *
     * @return Articles
     */
    public function addArticlesCategorie(ArticlesCategories $articleCategorie){
        $this->articlesCategories[] = $articleCategorie;
        $articleCategorie->setCodeArticle($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * remove articlesCategorie
     *
     * @param ArticlesCategories $articlesCategorie
     */
    public function removeArticlesCategorie(ArticlesCategories $articlesCategorie){
        $this->articlesCategories->removeElement($articlesCategorie);
    }

    /**
     * Get articlesCategories
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getArticlesCategories(){
        return $this->articlesCategories;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->codeArticle;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articlesCategories = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

This is the code of the relation ArticlesCategories:

```
/**
 * ArticlesCategories
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles_categories")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticlesCategoriesRepository")
 */
class ArticlesCategories
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Articles", inversedBy="articlesCategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="code_article", nullable=false)
     */
    private $codeArticle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="reference", nullable=false)
     */
    private $codeCategorie;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="critere_rech_1", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $critereRech1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="critere_rech_2", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $critereRech2;
```

And my entite Categories has nothing specific.

I generate automatically the crud of my entitie Articles, then I edit the class ArticlesType to have all attributes of my relation ArticlesCategories who are displays. To do this edition I use CollectionType.

This the code of my Form ArticlesType :

```
class ArticlesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('codeArticle')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('ecotaxe')
            ->add('qteMaxCde')
            ->add('publication')
            ->add('designation')
            ->add('taxonomie')
            ->add('referenceStock')
            ->add('articleRegroupement')
            ->add('articleAssocie1')
            ->add('articleAssocie2')
            ->add('articleAssocie3')
            ->add('seuilDegressif')
            ->add('tauxDegressif')
            ->add('articlesCategories', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ArticlesCategoriesType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => 'test',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'collection-articlesCategories'),
                'auto_initialize' => true
            ));
    }

    public function getName(){
        return 'Articles';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Articles'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_articles';
    }


}
```

When I go on the Article edition page that was generates by Symfony, I get the right display.
[Edition page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvid9.jpg)
But When I click on the button "Edit", I get this error : Could not determine access type for property "articlesCategories" in class "AppBundle\Entity\Articles".

I don't see where is my mistake.

I hope I am clear.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the following:

```
public function setArticlesCategories(...) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my code, I already write it in my entity. 
And I always have the error. 
Thank you to your answer !

Comment: sorry, i didn't see it... its weird that its on the bottom, you should put it on the upper portion of your code. IMHO

Comment: have you tried putting setArticlesCategories(...) ?

Comment: The order of the constructor don't change anything. But add setArticlesCategories(...) to my entity work ! So this topic is solve ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Hi @Lucie I edited my answer, if you may can you  mark this as the answer? Thanks!